# In Python: how do I repeatedly Create and Delete a Turtle window?

Tags: python, screen, turtle-graphics

I want to do something like this (but nothing I've tried so far works) in my Python program:

a1.  create a Turtle screen: `my_turtle_window = turtle.Screen ()`

a2.  create a Turtle: `my_turtle_list.append (turtle.Turtle ())`

a3.  do some Turtle drawing: `my_turtle_list [number_of_my_turtles - 1].pendown ()`

a4.  remove the Turtle screen: `my_turtle_window.bye ()`

b1.  create a Turtle screen: `my_turtle_window = turtle.Screen ()`

b2.  create a Turtle: `my_turtle_list.append (turtle.Turtle ())`

b3.  do some Turtle drawing: `my_turtle_list [number_of_my_turtles - 1].pendown ()`

b4.  remove the Turtle screen: `my_turtle_window.bye ()`

c1.  create a Turtle screen: `my_turtle_window = turtle.Screen ()`

c2.  create a Turtle: `my_turtle_list.append (turtle.Turtle ())`

c3.  do some Turtle drawing: `my_turtle_list [number_of_my_turtles - 1].pendown ()`

c4.  remove the Turtle screen: `my_turtle_window.bye ()`

but Turtle library code always crashes at step b2, and I have no idea why.
In other words: you don't seem to be able to start again with a new Turtle screen.
Grateful for any help ! :)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please consider checking out [what topics can you ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), SO is for solving specific problems with programming, you should provide a code you have tried so far, describe problems, showing effort in trying to solve it yourself at first (what have you read before etc.), "I need to do this, give me the code" questions are mostly closed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in what `turtle.bye` does; once it's called, you may not continue to call turtle methods. The error can be reproduced with this simple code:

```
import turtle

turtle.bye()
turtle.forward(100)
```

Instead of using `turtle.bye()`, you can use [`turtle.clear()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.clear):

```
import turtle

my_turtle_list = list()

my_turtle_window = turtle.Screen()
my_turtle_list.append(turtle.Turtle())
my_turtle_list[len(my_turtle_list) - 1].pendown()
my_turtle_window.clear()

my_turtle_window = turtle.Screen()
my_turtle_list.append(turtle.Turtle())
my_turtle_list[len(my_turtle_list) - 1].pendown()
my_turtle_window.clear()

my_turtle_window = turtle.Screen()
my_turtle_list.append(turtle.Turtle())
my_turtle_list[len(my_turtle_list) - 1].pendown()
my_turtle_window.clear()
```

Note: Instead of finding the amount of existing turtles each time to get the last turtle, use the indice `-1`, which gives you the last element of an array:

```
import turtle

my_turtle_list = list()

my_turtle_window = turtle.Screen()
my_turtle_list.append(turtle.Turtle())
my_turtle_list[-1].pendown()
my_turtle_window.clear()

my_turtle_window = turtle.Screen()
my_turtle_list.append(turtle.Turtle())
my_turtle_list[-1].pendown()
my_turtle_window.clear()

my_turtle_window = turtle.Screen()
my_turtle_list.append(turtle.Turtle())
my_turtle_list[-1].pendown()
my_turtle_window.clear()
```

Finally, with the `clear()` function, there is no need to redefine the screen each time:

```
import turtle

my_turtle_list = list()
my_turtle_window = turtle.Screen()

my_turtle_list.append(turtle.Turtle())
my_turtle_list[-1].pendown()
my_turtle_window.clear()

my_turtle_list.append(turtle.Turtle())
my_turtle_list[-1].pendown()
my_turtle_window.clear()

my_turtle_list.append(turtle.Turtle())
my_turtle_list[-1].pendown()
my_turtle_window.clear()
```